# destination of python persistent memoization

Tags: python

I want to write a decorator that does persistent memoization (memoizing to disk). Since I want to use this decorator for many functions, I have to decide where to save memoizing data for these functions. I googled around and found two solutions:

1. let the functions decide where to store the memoizing data
2. automatically determine where to store the data by function names

However, in these two solutions, it is necessary for every function to "know" each other in case of colliding of names (or destinations), which is a smell of bad design.

Thus, my question is, how to avoid such collidings?

Comment: The [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) which has to solve a similar problem uses the "fully qualified name" for pickling functions.

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't have an answer. I do however, have a couple of comments. :) 1. The functions that you decorate shouldn't know that they're decorated, so they shouldn't contain code or data relating to the memoization destination. OTOH, your decorator could choose a default destination based on the `__file__` and function's `.__name__`, but also accept an argument to choose a different destination path, or to modify the default one. 2. Take care to ensure that your program can handle being run more than once simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it in something next to or related to `__file__`, which is the path to the file the module was loaded from.  I believe in some cases it can be a relative path, so you might want to store the memos in that path directly, or turn it into an absolute path or something.